# How do I call a method from a different script? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

I have three scripts:

> main.py

> encrypt.py

and

> decrypt.py

Inside of main.py, I want to run encrypt.py or decrypt.py based on user input.

My code is listed below:

```
PATH = r"/path/to/scripts" + "/"

#This is where you guys come in

def encryption():
    #Execute PATH + encrypt.py
def decryption():
    #Execute PATH + decrypt.py

if __name__ == "__main__":
    encrypt_or_decrypt = input("Do you want to [1] encrypt or [2] decrypt? ")
    if encrypt_or_decrypt == 1:
        encryption()
    else:
        decryption()
```

Comment: import the files and call the functions/methods from inside main?

Comment: @TheLazyScripter would I do that as I would any other package? from decrypt import do_decrypt?

Comment: Yes, if the modules are accessible either by being relative to this package or within the project, or in the path. It appears that the files are next to each other, so you can directly call `import encrypt` or `from encrypt import what_i_need`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to simply run them like scripts then you could use the `subprocess` module.

```py
import subprocess

PATH = r"/path/to/scripts" + "/"

def encryption():
    subprocess.Popen(['python3', PATH + 'encrypt.py'])
def decryption():
    subprocess.Popen(['python3', PATH + 'decrypt.py'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    encrypt_or_decrypt = input("Do you want to [1] encrypt or [2] decrypt? ")
    if encrypt_or_decrypt == 1:
        encryption()
    else:
        decryption()
```